# Javascript: Detailed differences between !variable and variable == false?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I accidentally got `undefined == true` and `undefined == false` that both of them returns false.

But `!undefined` returns true.

And this is the question:

**What's the algorithmic difference(s) between `!someVariable` and `someVariable == false`?**

If i want to explain it more, type `undefined == false ? 't' : 'f'` in your browser's console, and it returns, `'f'` ( as explained above ).

But if you type `!undefined ? 't' : 'f'` it returns `'t'`.

So obviously there's difference(s) between them and how they're working.

**Update:**
I'm asking what does javascript do after we write `!someVar` or `someVar == false`. I guess the second one convert both of them to a comparable value and compares them? What's about the first one?

Comment: You are confusing the litteral `false` and false**y** values. You can convert a falsey value to false by adding `!!` in front of it: `!!undefined == false ? 't' : 'f'`

Comment: [This](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/136908/why-use-boolean-variable-over-boolean-variable-false) might be relevant here.

Comment: @blex Thanks for your comment, but I'm asking, is `false` a falsey value? If it is, so why two falsey value doesn't equal to each other on the `==` comparison?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`undefined` is not a boolean value so when you use `!` operator, your value will be converted to boolean at first.
but `==` operator just checking your values.

so if you want to get true from `undefined == false` you should do it like `Boolean(undefined) == false ? 't' : 'f'`

or the short way like `!!undefined == false`

`==` will convert both side to number like `Number(undefined) == Number(false)` and because `Number(undefined)` is NaN and `Number(false)` is 0 the result is false.

just like `'true' == true` is false but `Boolean('true') == true` is true

Comment: I suppose I've asked wrong question! The question is what's the path after we write `!var` and the path after we write `var == false`. Does the first one convert it straightforward to boolean and the second one convert them to number? Boolean? or something else?

Comment: exactly, you can see `Number(false)` return 0 but `Number(undefined)` return NaN

Comment: exactly what? `==` doesn't convert things around it?

Comment: `==` will convert both side to number

Comment: `==` always converts items to number? What's about `'string' == 'string'`?

Answer (score 2):

From the [ECMAScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.1):

> 11.9.1 The Equals Operator ( == )
>
> The production EqualityExpression : EqualityExpression ==
>   RelationalExpression is evaluated as follows:
>
> Let lref be the result of evaluating EqualityExpression. Let lval be
>   GetValue(lref). Let rref be the result of evaluating
>   RelationalExpression. Let rval be GetValue(rref). Return the result of
>   performing abstract equality comparison rval == lval. (see 11.9.3).

.

> 11.4.9 Logical NOT Operator ( ! )
>
> The production UnaryExpression : ! UnaryExpression is evaluated as
>   follows:
>
> Let expr be the result of evaluating UnaryExpression. Let oldValue be
>   ToBoolean(GetValue(expr)). If oldValue is true, return false. Return
>   true.

What you're looking at are two expressions:

`!someVariable` will use `ToBoolean()` and invert the result.

`someVariable == false` will evaluate to true or false by an equality comparison.

Also keep in mind that `==` and `===` are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

'!' operator first simply invert the value of variable/result occuring in front of it and then check it.
But `a==b` will compare the actual value of `a` and `b`.

For eg.:: `Object p=null;

if(!(p==null))System.out.println("hi");`

In above case `p==null` will return true but `!` will invert the result and check for trueness of that result i.e. if `p` **is not null** then print "hi".
As we know ::
`inverse of undefined is undefined`
**and** `undefined is not equal to any value among true or false` because `true` is binary 1 and `false` is binary 0 but  `undefined` is some garbage value and `null` is also some garbage value.
So on comparing them using `==` operator result **will always be false** but `!undefined` is `undefined` itself so result is `true`.
Hope, this will help you in understanding detailed difference b/w the operations of `!` and `==` on `undefined` or on any other variable .

Comment: I think "*`!undefined` is `undefined` itself so result is `true`*" is incorrect, because `undefined == true` returns false.

Comment: @mrReiha As I wrote `undefined==true` will always return `false` because we are comparing a garbage value ,like `null` to a binary `1` in JavaScript.  `!undefined` is `undefined` always .This concept is used in DBMS for returning results of a query.